# workaround SPAM in Catch-all email

Tags: python, google-app-engine, catch-all

We are building a website expecting to serve around 10k users or more.

We want a functionality that each user will have an email address @ our domain, however, this email address will not be accessible by the user it will only be used to receive a very rare amount of emails (say it will be published to receive gift cards directed to that user) and we need to notify the user as any gift card is received and do something accordingly at our end

We want to use Google App Engine with Python, and what first came to our minds is that we don't actually create any real mailboxes and we create a single catch-all email that will receive any mail sent to our domain mailboxes even not existed, then we can filter all received emails and map them to our users accounts

Within current Google receive limits (1 email per second) this will work, the main issue is that SPAM mails comes and flood the catch-all mail box with emails that directly reach receive limit and email account gets suspended by Google

We want to apply a smarter solution, we only care for emails that comes from a specific sender domain (say: giftcards.com) and we can drop any other emails

Is there is any reliable service or setup at our side we can use to filter out unwanted emails and only forward emails from giftcards.com (for example) to our main Google apps email?

Comment: Have you considered using a third party service, such as Sendgrid?  The service can receive emails on your behalf and then send the info to your app engine app.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your help, I just checked Sendgrid and it has a very good option that perfectly fit my need "Inbound Parse Webhook"
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Inbound_Parse_Webhook/setting_up_the_inbound_parse_webhook.html
If I can trust that this is a reliable service that will deliver within seconds of original email receipt and no emails ever will be dropped, this will even remove all email parse/check headache. Thank you